# Array initializer error

Tags: c#, xna

When trying to add variables of type CubeDescriptor to an array, I get the error Error: Array initializers can only be used in a variable or field initializer. Try using a new expression instead. I've looked at some other topics on this forum but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

```
public class CubeDescriptor
{
    public EcubeType CubeType;
    public Texture2D Texture;
    public bool isMineable;
}

public static CubeDescriptor[] TypeTable = {
                                            {EcubeType.Air, null, false},
                                            {EcubeType.Grass, grass, false},
                                            {EcubeType.Stone, stone, true}
                                           };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class CubeDescriptor
{
    public EcubeType CubeType;
    public Texture2D Texture;
    public bool isMineable;
}

public static CubeDescriptor[] TypeTable = new {
                                               new CubeDescriptor(EcubeType.Air, null, false),
                                               new CubeDescriptor(EcubeType.Grass, grass, false),
                                               new CubeDescriptor(EcubeType.Stone, stone, true)

                                           };
```

EDIT:

If you don't have a constructor then you could do

```
public static CubeDescriptor[] TypeTable = new {
                                               new CubeDescriptor {CubeType = EcubeType.Air, Texture2D = null, isMineable = false},
                                               new CubeDescriptor {CubeType = EcubeType.Grass, Texture2D = grass, isMineable = false},
                                               new CubeDescriptor {CubeType = EcubeType.Stone, Texture2D = stone, isMineable = true}

                                           };
```

Comment: That doesn't help at all.

Comment: Hmm I just realized I dont even have a constructor for that class

Comment: That gives me this error: Cannot initialize type 'Cube_Chaser.Cube2.CubeDescriptor' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: Eh I ended up just making a constructor anyways. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

C# does not support C-style structure initialization.

To fill your array with `CubeDescriptor`, you need to call the `CubeDescriptor` constructor to create a new instance.

You can set the field using object initializer syntax:

```
new CubeDescriptor { CubeType = ..., Texture = ..., ... }
```

Comment: So something like TypeTable[0] = new CubeDescriptor(blah, blah, blah)?